# Ubuntu 10.04 - Problem creating Xorg.conf for DualView

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, matrox

so far I found out that I need to configure the Xorg.conf to have DualView on my monitor. At this moment the screen is just duplicated. My Graphics Card is Matrox G550.

When trying

> jannis@Ariel:/$ sudo Xorg -configure
>
> Fatal server error: Server is already active for display 0    If this
>   server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock     and start again.
>
> Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support    at
>   http://wiki.x.org  for help.
>
> ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log

Also `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` doesn't exist..

Since I allready tried it a several months ago, lost my X configuration and needed to reinstall the OS I am terrified it can happen again.

Does anyone know what to do? Is there anyway to store the current/running configuration and restore it afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop xserver first. The procedure goes something like this:

1. Switch to tty1 by pressing `ctrl-alt-f1`
2. Become root: `sudo -i`.
3. Stop xserver: `service gdm stop`.
4. Run `Xorg -configure`.

A config file will be written into /root/xorg.conf.new. Copy that to the proper location.

1. Copying: `cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
2. Restart xserver: `service gdm start`
3. Exit from root: `exit`
4. Return to tty7: ctrl-alt-f7.

Comment: thanks for that response! Will my current(working) configuration be  modified or changed? Will everything work like it does now?

Comment: The above steps will create an `xorg.conf` config file. Whether it will work, or how well, I don't know. In case it breaks something, just remove or rename /etc/X11/xorg.conf. As for modifying, there was no xorg.conf, and so nothing to modify.